# Only making part of text bold in Powerbuilder expression

Tags: string, powerbuilder, bold, computed-field, infomaker

Is it possible to make only a specific part of a string **bold** in a computed field or text object.

Answer (score 1):

Try a RichText control. It will give you more control over the look of the text.